# implication of "no matter how much one does something"

Tags: implication

Is there a contradiction in the following? Does "no matter how much he talks" imply he talks a lot?

> He doesn't talk much. No matter how much he talks, no one believes him.

> He doesn't talk much, because no matter how much he talks, no one believes him.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The second sentence would be better as "No matter what he says, no one believes him" or just "He doesn't talk much – no one believes what he says."

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "no matter how much he talks" does not imply anything about how much he talks. It means that what follows does not depend on how much he talks.
That being so, your first two sentences are disconnected, and illogical in sequence.
The third sentence, with the word "because", makes sense. It points out that he is not believed, whether he talks a lot or a little, and so he has decided not to talk much.